# Is using ObjectDataSource a good practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my company few of the employees are using ObjectDataSource. Example snippet is :

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsRequirement" runat="server" EnablePaging="True" 
                      MaximumRowsParameterName="intMaxRows"
                      SelectMethod="GetAll" 
                      StartRowIndexParameterName="intRowIndex" 
                      TypeName="MyNamespace.MyType" 
                      SortParameterName="SortString"
                      OnSelecting="odsRequirement_Selecting"
                      SelectCountMethod="GetAllCount">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="A" DefaultValue="null" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="B" DefaultValue="null" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="C" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="D" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="E" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Will the SelectCountMethod **GetAllCount** be always fired after the SelectMethod **GetAll**?  And is there a better way we should be doing this?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Whoever wrote the class from which that data is being pulled should read the framework design guidelines.  Those parameter names are horrendous.  strUgh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'm not a big fan of these types of controls. I much prefer getting data from the code-behind and binding the data to the page. My problem is that you're baking domain logic into the ASPX page itself. I'd recommend seperating that by moving the code which gets the data into another class, which should be in another layer (i.e. Domain, or Model - which are usually class libraries).

Regardless, try to get away from using this control and move the data gathering logic into another file. In the long term, you will see the benefits.

http://geekswithblogs.net/opiesblog/archive/2006/09/11/90906.aspx

Comment: Data gathering logic is already into another class. As you can see ObjectDataSource control has a property named `Type`. This is the name of your Business Logic class that pulls data from sql server. The SelectMethod is the name of the method that fires and is reponsible for returning a List<T>

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was - if your data gathering class changes at all, then you will need to update all of the ObjectDataSource controls which reference that class. It's better just to pass the data to the ASPX page. It's not the job of the ASPx page to get the data - it's shouldn't care where the data comes from, it's job is to show it. But that's a personal preference though :)

Comment: Thanks and are there any performance issues with ObjectDatSource? because as far as I know it uses Reflection magic to call and pass parameters. I am not sure though.

Comment: Yeah I would imaging there is a hit. Try using the `StopWatch` class to measure how long calls are taking. Reflection is always going to cost you a bit in this case.